# Vectorise image block processing efficiently?

Tags: c++, image, sse, simd, neon

I am curious what is the most efficient method when I process image block-by-block.

At that moment, I applied some vectorization technics such as I read one row of pixels (8 pixels a row, each 8-bit depth) from an 8x8 block. But as modern processors support 128/256-bit vector operation, I think loading two rows of pixels from the image block can improve code speed.

But the problem is, an image(for example 16x16 image, contains 4 8x8 blocks) in memory is stored from the first pixel to the last pixel continuously. The loading of one 8-pixel row of is easy, but how should I operate the pointer or align image data so that I could load 2 rows together?

I think this figure can illustrate my problem clearly:
[pixels' address in a image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0c4XR.png)

So, when we load 8 pixels (a row) together, we simply load 8 bytes data from the initial pointer position by 1 instruction. When we load 2nd row, we simply add 9 to the pointer and load the second row.

So, the questions is, is there any method that we could load these two rows (16 pixels) together from the initial pointer position?

Thanks!

Comment: When you say *"load"*, do you mean read from a file? Or put into CPU registers from RAM?

Comment: I mean put data into CPU register from RAM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make each row aligned, you can pad the end of each row.  Writing your code to support a shorter image width than the stride between rows lets your algorithm work on a subset of an image.

Also, you don't actually need everything to be aligned for SIMD to work well.  Contiguous is sufficient.  Most SIMD instruction sets (SSE, NEON, etc.) have unaligned load instructions.  Depending on the specific implementation, there might not be much penalty.

---

You don't load two different rows into the same SIMD vector.  For example, to do an 8x8 SAD (sum of absolute differences) using AVX2 VPSADBW, each 32-byte load would get data from one row of four different 8x8 blocks.  But that's fine, you just use that to produce four 8x8 SAD results in parallel, instead of wasting a lot of time shuffling to do a single 8x8 SAD.

For example, [Intel's MPSADBW tutorial](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/motion-estimation-with-intel-streaming-simd-extensions-4-intel-sse4) shows how to implement an exhaustive motion search for 4x4, 8x8, and 16x16 blocks, with C and Intel's SSE intrinsics.  Apparently the actual MPSADBW instruction isn't actually worth using in practice, though, because it's slower than PSADBW and you can get identical results faster with a sequential elimination exhaustive search, as used by x264 (and mentioned by x264 developers in [this forum thread](http://forum.doom9.org/showthread.php?t=133567) about whether SSE4.1 would help x264.)

Some SIMD-programming blog posts from the archives of Dark Shikari's blog: Diary Of An x264 Developer:

- [Cacheline splits, take two](http://web.archive.org/web/20120417184641/http://x264dev.multimedia.cx/archives/96): using PALIGNR or other techniques to set up unaligned inputs for motion searches
- [A curious SIMD assembly challenge: the zigzag](http://web.archive.org/web/20140807014206/http://x264dev.multimedia.cx/archives/232)

Comment: But even if we pad zeros at the end of each row, I don't understand how to load two rows in a block together? I guess unaligned load instructions don't help load tow rows in one instruction?

Comment: Do you want to set up the code that compiler vectorises it for you? Or do the hard work yourself? There is no advantage in the later if the compiler gets the same result, and if/when you go to a new AVX, or other architecture then you need to "hand do it" all again. All the #pragma stuff can often give the compiler enough to sort it out, depending on how it handles pointers and contiguous access.

Comment: @drinking: You load the same row from multiple blocks, and process multiple blocks in parallel so you don't need to do that.  See my updated answer.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Yes. the update makes sense to me. In your update, we compute the left 8x8 block and right 8x8 block in parallel.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Sorry for the last comment, I didn't finish it and it seems like I can't edit it after submit... 

Thanks for the answer. The update makes a lot of sense to me. 

But what if the search window in image processing is not that large? For example, search an 8x8 block in a 14x14 image searching window is quite common in practice. 14x14 search window even doesn't allow us to load the same row from 2 blocks.

Comment: @drinking: The 14x14 search window is just a subset of a larger image, and you can do two or four 8x8 motion-searches in parallel.  You inevitably need unaligned loads for this, or else you need a lot of shuffling to build vectors of different offsets in the target.  See this Intel white-paper on using SSE2 PSADBW or SSE4 MPSADBW for exhaustive motion search.  (But don't actually do that;  mathematically equivalent [sequential elimination](http://forum.doom9.org/showthread.php?t=133567) is possible, giving the identical results faster than a brute-force MPSADBW.)

Comment: @Holmz: I think yes, I will do the hard work... Because I am using NEON on iPhone. All information I googled said the Clang is quite rubbish when compiling code for NEON... it just use some stupid staffs to slow codes down. So I guess the better solution is to modify the assembly file generated by compiler, instead of writing whole part by hand...

Comment: @drinking: BTW, that Intel paper is doing 4x4 motion searches, so they do need to interleave their vector loads to get two rows of each 4x4 block into 8 consecutive bytes of a vector, because PSADBW does works in chunks of 8 input bytes.  The less shuffling you need to do, the better, but that's the other way to address the problem you're talking about.

Comment: @drinking: can you link something you read about Clang making a mess with NEON intrinsics?  I forget what I've read, but I doubt that's true of current versions of clang.  And if you get bad results with clang, can you just use gcc?  Writing NEON with intrinsics is the recommended way, from what I've seen in SO answers even from people that *do* know exactly how to write stuff in asm, and answer lots of ARM assembly questions.  Intrinsics are the only way to manually vectorize for AArch64 and ARM(32) without a lot of ifdefs.

Comment: @drinking: Depending on what you're doing, [GNU C vector extensions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Vector-Extensions.html) may give you a way to vectorize for ARM and x86 the same way.  But there aren't cross-platform builtins for a lot of special stuff, like PSADBW.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for the updates and detailed explanations. I am a newbie just getting into optimisation and not quite familiar with these compilers, and getting deep to different compilers is not suit for my task at that moment. I think I will write some intrinsics and assembly to compare their performance. I will have a much easier life if intrinsics work fine! Also, I will check out the intel papers about 4x4 motion searches to see which method are optimum for me!

Comment: @drinking:  That's fine, it's probably easier to learn if you just vectorize separately for x86 and ARM with "normal" intrinsics, instead of trying to share part of the code with Vector Extensions.  But gcc, clang, and icc all support GNU C vector extensions.  Maybe there are some ARM compilers that don't support GNU extensions, IDK.  They're a GNU extension just like other extensions to the C language, like statement-expressions, or GNU-style inline asm.